# Selecting multiple columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, netezza

I've constructed the flowing SQL for my netezza db:

```
select t.TRADE_OID, t.TRADE_ID, t.TRADE_VERSION, t.TRADE_SOURCE_SYSTEM, tl.LINK_PARENT_ID, 
tl.LINK_PARENT_VERSION, tc.CHARGE_AMOUNT FROM EQ_MO_TRADE (NOLOCK) t, EQ_MO_TRADE_CHARGE (NOLOCK) tc, EQ_MO_TRADE_LINKAGE (NOLOCK) tl 
WHERE t.Last_update_time >= '2013-01-09 00:00:00' 
AND t.last_update_time < '2013-01-10 00:00:00' 
AND t.TRADE_OID = tl.TRADE_OID
AND t.TRADE_OID = tc.TRADE_OID
AND tc.CHARGE_NAME = 'Commission'
```

However I'm given the general error:

```
 [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1100, SQL State: HY000]  ERROR:  'select 

t.TRADE_OID, t.TRADE_ID, t.TRADE_VERSION, t.TRADE_SOURCE_SYSTEM, tl.LINK_PARENT_ID, tl.LINK_PARENT_VERSION, tc.CHARGE_AMOUNT FROM EQ_MO_TRADE (NOLOCK) t, EQ_MO_TRADE_CHARGE (NOLOCK) tc, EQ_MO_TRADE_LINKAGE (NOLOCK) tl 
WHERE t.Last_update_time >= '2013-01-09 00:00:00' 
AND t.last_update_time < '2013-01-10 00:00:00' 
AND t.TRADE_OID = tl.TRADE_OID
AND t.TRADE_OID = tc.TRADE_OID
AND tc.CHARGE_NAME = 'Commission' limit 1000'
error                                                                                                                                                         

^ found "(" (at char 150) expecting `EXCEPT' or `FOR' or `INTERSECT' or `ORDER
```

Character 150 is between these two:

Trade and (NOLOCK)

My syntax seems correct but DBVisualiser won't run the query.

Comment: Have you tried without (NOLOCK) in the `FROM` clause?

Comment: The full syntax in for an optimizer hint like `NOLOCK` is `WITH (NOLOCK)`. As you no doubt are aware `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation can cause issues like phantom reads etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the [Netezza Database User's Guide (5.0.x)](http://www.enzeecommunity.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/1161-102-1-1107/Netezza_database_users_guide.pdf), Netezza does not support Optimizer hints like `WITH (NOLOCK)`.

From page 3.36

> > Note that there is no need for user intervention, commands, or hints

In any event, `NOLOCK` is widely regarded as [dubious practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452996/is-the-nolock-sql-server-hint-bad-practice).

However, Netezza does support `INNER JOIN` Syntax (p2.17)

I would rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT
    t.TRADE_OID, 
    t.TRADE_ID, 
    t.TRADE_VERSION, 
    t.TRADE_SOURCE_SYSTEM, 
    tl.LINK_PARENT_ID, 
    tl.LINK_PARENT_VERSION, 
    tc.CHARGE_AMOUNT 
FROM 
  EQ_MO_TRADE t 
    INNER JOIN EQ_MO_TRADE_CHARGE tc
            ON (t.TRADE_OID = tc.TRADE_OID)
    INNER JOIN EQ_MO_TRADE_LINKAGE tl 
        ON (t.TRADE_OID = tl.TRADE_OID)
WHERE 
  t.Last_update_time >= '2013-01-09 00:00:00' 
  AND t.last_update_time < '2013-01-10 00:00:00' 
  AND tc.CHARGE_NAME = 'Commission'
```