# Is this the good practice(performance wise) to create multiple views on same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql database which contains millions of records. In my application I want to query this table on different column bases. I have created view for this table where all columns exist. I want to know is this the good practice to create multiple views on different column bases ?

Comment: view is simply a query... it doesn't take any resources to upkeep/maintain... duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169/is-it-okay-to-have-a-lot-of-database-views

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to have a lot of database views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169/is-it-okay-to-have-a-lot-of-database-views)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem for the perfomance is how mysql handle views.

Here is a good anwser from Derek Downey: [on dba stackexchnage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16372/when-to-use-views-in-mysql)